# Printing two python lists next to each other with regard to similar items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently playing around with python to deal with duplicate music files. For that I'm looking for a more pythonic way to print 2 lists (length could be unequal) next to each other. It is import though, that the items, which have a similar name are in the same row and it would be great, if it wouldn't matter which lists contains more items. The Formatting could also be a bit better.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
a = ['01-06 How Does It Feel.mp3', '01-08 Never Walk Away.mp3']

b = ['01 Show Me a Sign.mp3',
 "02 Don't Let Go.mp3",
 '03 All Messed Up.mp3',
 '04 Promise Keeper.mp3',
 '05 Goodbye to You.mp3',
 '06 How Does It Feel.mp3',
 '07 Had Enough of You.mp3',
 '08 Never Walk Away.mp3',
 '09 Nothing Left at All.mp3',
 '10 Reality Show.mp3',
 '11 Killing With Kindness.mp3']


def checkTitleName(org, song):
    for i in org:
        if song in i:
            return i
        
    return None
    

def listViewCompare(org, dub):
    out = ""
    for i in dub:
        match = checkTitleName(org, i)
        if  match == None:
            line = [i, "\t\t --> \t"]
            print(out.join(line))

        else:
            line = [i, "\t\t --> \t", match]
            print(out.join(line))

                
print(listViewCompare(a,b))
```

Output:

```
01 Show Me a Sign.mp3        -->    
02 Don't Let Go.mp3      -->    
03 All Messed Up.mp3         -->    
04 Promise Keeper.mp3        -->    
05 Goodbye to You.mp3        -->    
06 How Does It Feel.mp3      -->    01-06 How Does It Feel.mp3
07 Had Enough of You.mp3         -->    
08 Never Walk Away.mp3       -->    01-08 Never Walk Away.mp3
09 Nothing Left at All.mp3       -->    
10 Reality Show.mp3      -->    
11 Killing With Kindness.mp3         -->    
None
```

Comment: More Pythonic in what way? There's a lot of stuff that could be improved here. What are you looking for specifically? If you want overall advice, it'd probably be better to ask on [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: Like I said, for example, it would be nice if it wouldn't matter which list is longer. In general, I'm looking for some functions which could do the same with less code. I tried it with the knowledge I had.

Comment: OK, if `org` is longer than `dub`, what's your expected output? What if they don't overlap? But actually, if you're looking for duplicates, why do you even care about the items that don't overlap? I mean, why not just print the duplicates and nothing more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
a = ['01-06 How Does It Feel.mp3', '01-08 Never Walk Away.mp3']

b = [
    '01 Show Me a Sign.mp3',
     "02 Don't Let Go.mp3",
     '03 All Messed Up.mp3',
     '04 Promise Keeper.mp3',
     '05 Goodbye to You.mp3',
     '06 How Does It Feel.mp3',
     '07 Had Enough of You.mp3',
     '08 Never Walk Away.mp3',
     '09 Nothing Left at All.mp3',
     '10 Reality Show.mp3',
     '11 Killing With Kindness.mp3',
]


length = max(len(s) for s in b)

for i in b:
    for j in a:
        if i in j[3:]:
            print(f"{i:{length}} -> {j}")
    print(f"{i:{length}} ->")
```

Output:

```
01 Show Me a Sign.mp3        ->
02 Don't Let Go.mp3          ->
03 All Messed Up.mp3         ->
04 Promise Keeper.mp3        ->
05 Goodbye to You.mp3        ->
06 How Does It Feel.mp3      -> 01-06 How Does It Feel.mp3
06 How Does It Feel.mp3      ->
07 Had Enough of You.mp3     ->
08 Never Walk Away.mp3       -> 01-08 Never Walk Away.mp3
08 Never Walk Away.mp3       ->
09 Nothing Left at All.mp3   ->
10 Reality Show.mp3          ->
11 Killing With Kindness.mp3 ->
```

Comment: `itertools` is unused?

Comment: @baduker Thanks for the formatting idea, I will look into this.

Comment: @wjandrea how would itertools improve the code?

Comment: @Max2603 Oh, baduker removed it? I thought they were going to use `itertools.product`.

Comment: @Max2603 if you find my answer useful, consider up-voting and/or accepting it.